# How to stop flying up objects by itself?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a stack from cubes what are break for 2 small cubes when collide with specific object. After break the cubes should sliding on sides but they are flying up by itself when I collide the stacks with my object little faster. Can I stop that in any simple way and give the small cubes permission to only sliding on sides (left right) on X axis?

```
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(_pos.x, victim.position.y, victim.position.z);
Vector3 victimScale = victim.localScale;
float distance = Vector3.Distance(victim.position, pos);
if (distance >= victimScale.x/2) return false;

Vector3 leftPoint = victim.position - Vector3.right * victimScale.x/2;
Vector3 rightPoint = victim.position + Vector3.right * victimScale.x/2;
Material mat = victim.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
Destroy(victim.gameObject);

GameObject rightSideObj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
rightSideObj.transform.position = (rightPoint + pos) /2;
float rightWidth = Vector3.Distance(pos,rightPoint);
rightSideObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3( rightWidth ,victimScale.y ,victimScale.z );
rightSideObj.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
rightSideObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mat;

GameObject leftSideObj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
leftSideObj.transform.position = (leftPoint + pos)/2;
float leftWidth = Vector3.Distance(pos,leftPoint);
leftSideObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3( leftWidth ,victimScale.y ,victimScale.z );
leftSideObj.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
leftSideObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mat;
```

There is a code what I'm using for break big cubes to 2 small cubes.
For sliding the leftsideobj and rightsideobj on sides I'm using a AddForce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's break, not brake.

You can put a [constraint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Constraints.html) on the pieces to disallow motion along y or z axes.

Comment: I just used the constraint. And that gives for me the effect what I'm looking for. Thx.